# Opacity and overlapping multiple polygons

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing

Let's say I have 100 polygons that are all different but most of them overlap.  All I want to do is to draw/plot them in one single graphic with **linearly adding** gray values; i.e., a point with `n` overlapping polygons(or other graphics) should have a grayvalue of `n/100`.

I wish

```
Graphics[{Opacity[1/10], Table[Disk[{i/10, 0}], {i, 10}]}]
```

would work, but `Opacity` doesn't add up linearly, and I don't find any easy way to do what I want.

My current idea is to go via `Image[Graphics[...]]`, `ImageData` and `ArrayPlot`, but I might lose a lot of precision that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with [image-processing](/questions/tagged/image-processing) but I do not think you could get both, high precission and high performance, at once.

This is straightforward approach. With Image processing functions avalible in *Mathematica*. Also, I'm not going to use `Opacity`, I do not know how does it work inside.

First, there is a function to to create an image, you can set resulution like you need.

```
f = ColorConvert[Image[Graphics[#, PlotRange -> 1], 
                       "Bit", ImageResolution -> 96, ImageSize -> 500], 
                 "GrayScale"] &;
```

Lets create some triangles:

```
pics = f /@ (Polygon /@ Table[{{0, -1}, RandomReal[1, 2],RandomReal[{-1, 0}, 2]}, 
                              {100}]);

ImageMultiply[Fold[ImageAdd, First@pics, Rest@pics], 1/100]
```

[image]

Stealing examples with `Disk`s (*generating disk images last longer but not so much*):

```
f = ColorConvert[Image[Graphics[#, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-.5, .5}}], "Bit", 
                       ImageResolution -> 96, ImageSize -> 500], "GrayScale"] &;

pics = f /@ Table[Disk[{-.5 + i/100, 0}, .5], {i, 100}];

ob = ImageMultiply[Fold[ImageAdd, First@pics, Rest@pics], 1/100]
ColorNegate@ob
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see, everything is linear:

```
ListPlot[ImageData[ColorNegate@ob][[ 130]]]
```

[image]

Comment: So you are just adding up all Images and divide by #Images. Sounds simple, but those ways are often the best. I think I tried this before as well, but for some reasons it didn't work. €:thx, this (probably) was what I wanted

Comment: @ARizona Thank you, I'm glad you like it. `Fold` with `ImageAdd` is quite handy. If you want high precission you may try to work with inequalities which are describing polygons and `Piecewise` etc. but this is going to be so slow... :)

Answer (score 6):

In theory, the only way that overlaying $N$ objects with constant opacity will yield a completely opaque intersection is when $N \to \infty$. Therefore, it will be hard to get exactly what you want without resorting to image processing.

Here is a way to get the linear addition effect of intersecting gray-level objects using image tools:

```
With[{threshold = .05, n = 10},
 t = Table[
   Image[
    Graphics[
     {GrayLevel[threshold^(1/n)], Disk[{i/n, 0}]},
     PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 2.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
     ],
    ImageResolution -> 200
    ],
   {i, n}
   ];
 im = First[t //. {a___, x_, y_, b___} :> {a, ImageMultiply[x, y], b}];
 ImageApply[Log[Max[#, threshold]/threshold]/Log[1/threshold] &, im]]
```

[image: gray intersections]

Here I set `n` to be the number of overlapping shapes, and used your `Disk` example. The `ImageResolution` option can be used to your taste, to avoid the pixelated appearance you're worried about.

What I do is use `ImageMultiply` with a set of small `GrayLevel`s for each shape. This is then subjected to `ImageMultiply`, leading initially to (undesirable) *unequal* steps in gray scale for the intersections. The darkest color that I can get with the multiplication of `n` shapes is set by `threshold`.

To get the threshold value to display as truly `Black`, I post-process the resulting multiplied images with `ImageApply` by taking the `Log` of the pixel values, to undo the exponentially varying `GrayLevel` of the individual intersecting shapes. The `Log` is scaled such that its result varies between `0` and `1`.

By combining this geometric sequence of image gray levels with a `Log`, I end up with something that looks like addition of gray levels but achieves the full dynamic range between `0` and `1`.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer, but I do not understand why your first sentence should hold. Your approach looks a lot better then `Opacity[]` but gets quite slow for a few hundreds of Images and the `ImageApply` needs to be adjusted to give a darker black for a larger n.

Comment: It gets slow, but never slower than @Kuba's approach, as far as I can tell. Mathematically, you'll get `GrayLevel` zero *exactly* when there are `n` overlapping shapes. You can't get any blacker than `0`, so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach, but perhaps not meeting your precision requirement, is to create the `Graphics` using `Opacity` as you did, and then use image processing to adjust the levels.

```
op = 1/10;
m = 10;
gr = Graphics[{Opacity[op], Table[Disk[{i/10, 0}], {i, 10}]}]
```

[image]

The gray level from combining $n$ layers of opacity $\text{op}$ is $\text{col}=(1-\text{op})^n$, so to convert to a gray level of $n/m$ requires:

```
ImageApply[Log[#]/(m Log[1 - op]) &, Image[gr]]
```

[image]

To confirm that the resulting image has a gray level of $n/10$:

```
ListPlot[ImageData[%][[130, All, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried with 100 Disks and something is not correct. Do you confirm or I'm making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Kuba, `op = 1/50; m = 100; gr = 
 Graphics[{Opacity[op], Table[Disk[{i/50, 0}], {i, 100}]}]` doesn't look too bad. This approach is fundamentally limited by Mathematica's 8-bit rasterization of course, with enough disks you reach a point where *n* layers and *n+1* layers map to the same gray level.

Comment: Oh, it works. I've tried with `op=1/100` but it doesn't seem to be a problem you've mentioned, does it or I'm wrong again? :). Also, for `1/50` it looks good but it is not equal to `1` inside common area.

Comment: @Kuba, yes that's the result of my assuming continuously variable opacity when the rasterization is really done with 8 bits. I could probably tweak it to make it a little better, but really I just wanted to show that something close to linear could be recovered from the combined graphics rather than rasterizing each disk individually. Yours or Jens' is definitely the method to use if precision is important.

Comment: The idea is great (+1ed), unfortunately I have no knowledge about opacity and rasterization at this level so I will not say more. :)