# Is there a fast method of generating a Standard Deviation image from a frame stack?

Tags: image-processing, image

Imagine I have a stack of image frames, $(f_1, ..., f_N) \in F$, where each $f_i$ has the same set of $(x,y)$ dimensions.  Using these frames, I'd like to create an image where each pixel in the image consists of the standard deviation of the values at the corresponding pixel position in each of the $f_i$.

Unfortunately, the following procedure is painfully slow (when applied to a $256 \times 256$ pixel image):

```
SDImage = ImageData@FrameStack[[1]];
  For[a = 1, a <= ImageDimensions[FrameStack[[1]]][[1]], a++,
    For[b = 1, b <= ImageDimensions[FrameStack[[1]]][[2]], b++,
     SDImage[[a, b]] = StandardDeviation[Table[ImageData[FrameStack[[k]]][[a, b]], {k, 1, Length[FrameStack]}]];
     Print[SDImage[[a, b]]];
    ];
  ];

SDImage = Image[SDImage]
```

Is there a faster method of doing this, or perhaps a built in tool (like in ImageJ)?

Comment: By the way: The code you posted in your question might be painful slow because the procedural nature of the code. Trying to avoid `For` loops and using Mathematica build in functions is always a good way in making the code more efficient.

Comment: Related: [Averagind 2D datasets](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28993/5478). Or different approach for work [with multiple images](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29037/5478). Offtop: try to avoid you variable names starting with capital letters.

Comment: ["why loops in Mathematica are slow"](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/m_performance/m_performance.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have loaded a stack of images and stored in a variable called `imageStack` you can do the following to compute the standard deviation image over the entire stack:

```
imageStack = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff"];
xyStd = Image@Thread[StandardDeviation[ImageData /@ imageStack], {1}];
```

This gives you the standard deviation image in z direction of the stack. For the upper example `xyStd` gives the following image:

[image: Standard deviation image of engine example.]

**Edit**

As **Kuba** pointed out, a better solution would be:

```
StandardDeviation[ImageData /@ imageStack]
```

Comment: `StandardDeviation[ImageData /@ imageStack]` is enough.

Comment: @Kuba: right, thanks ;)

Comment: No problem :) I've made that mistake [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28993/5478)

Answer (score 6):

This is about 100 times faster than g3kk0's answer on my machine---the results are identical:

```
imageStack = Image[ColorCombine@Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "ImageList"], "Real"];
ImageApply[StandardDeviation, imageStack]
```

Comment: I can confirm the speedup.  Thank you!

Comment: Nice usage of `ColorCombine` and `ImageApply`. I can confirm a speedup of about 25 fold compared to my version.

Answer (score 2):

I wondered whether the built-in `StandardDeviationFilter` would work here (on Alexander's `imageStack`).

```
 StandardDeviationFilter[
 Image3D[
  imageStack, 
  ColorFunction -> "LowRange"],
 {Length[imageStack], 1, 1}]
```

[image: filtered engine]

It kind of works - but it's probably not the solution you're looking for.

Comment: That's a good suggestion - but I previously tried this, and in my particular case, the results are radically different.

Comment: @SparsePine Oh.

Comment: Perhaps this is better `StandardDeviationFilter[Image3D[imageStack], {Ceiling@Length[imageStack]/2, 0, 0}]` -- the last arguments are radii.  But it's several times slower than Alexander Schmitz's.

Comment: @cormullion Sorry, I think I came off as a bit rude there.  That really wasn't my intention.  I just meant to say that I tried the filter, and it just didn't work very well in my particular case.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @SparsePine No, I didn't think that... I was just surprised that you'd tried it. It's always worth mentioning what you've tried (and providing a small sample of your data). Image3d isn't very quick or dependable on my machine anyway...

Comment: @cormullion: I'm not quite sure about that, but doesn't the `StandardDeviationFilter` give something different in theory than taking the standard deviation over the stack? If the r parameter is set to one this means a 3x3 neighborhood and would explain the slightly blurred looking image in your answer.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmitz I'm not sure, I just looked up `StandardDeviation` in the online help. Michael's version is better, and taking the first image of the stack using `Image3DSlices` (you're looking at the whole stack here) gets quite close. Anyway, it was just a detour worth taking.. :)

Comment: @cormullion: it always is ;)