# Efficient image stacking

Tags: image-processing, image, performance-tuning

I have a list of lists of images that I would like to stack and create mean images for each list of images.
Images are `.jpg` files 2592x1944 pixels large. Each list contains about 300 images. This means I can't import them all at once due to limited computer memory.
I have tried several methods of importing and stacking the images. Each method was timed in a clean mathematica session (I have quit the kernel between executions).
Image file names are stored in `imghs`:

```
Length@imghs (* this is constant *)
```

> ```
> 24
> ```

```
Length /@ imghs (* this will increase with time *)
```

> ```
> {307, 310, 312, 311, 312, 311, 312, 311, 310, 311, 308, 308, 312, 309, 311, 310, 308, 313, 316, 314, 317, 317, 311, 316}
> ```

Here are my methods and timings:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 means = ParallelMap[
    ImageMultiply[
      Fold[ImageAdd[Image[#1, "Real"], Image[Import[#2], "Real"]] &, 
       Import[#[[1]]], #[[2 ;;]]], 1/Length[#]] &, 
    imghs[[1 ;; -1 ;; 6, 1 ;; 100]]];]
```

> ```
> {61.559226, Null}
> ```

```
DistributeDefinitions[i];
AbsoluteTiming[
 means2 = ParallelMap[(i = Image[Import[#[[1]]], "Real"]; 
      Do[i = ImageAdd[i, Image[Import[img]]], {img, #[[2 ;;]]}]; 
      i = ImageMultiply[i, 1/Length[#]]) &, 
    imghs[[1 ;; -1 ;; 6, 1 ;; 100]]];]
```

> ```
> {42.876076, Null}
> ```

```
DistributeDefinitions[i];
AbsoluteTiming[
 means3 = ParallelMap[(i = Import[#[[1]], "Data"]; 
      Do[i += Import[img, "Data"], {img, #[[2 ;;]]}]; 
      i *= 1/Length[#]; Image[i]) &, imghs[[1 ;; -1 ;; 6, 1 ;; 100]]];]
```

> ```
> {114.549350, Null}
> ```

```
SetSharedVariable[j];
AbsoluteTiming[
 means4 = Map[(j = Import[#[[1]], "Data"]; 
      ParallelDo[j += Import[img, "Data"], {img, #[[2 ;;]]}]; 
      j *= 1/Length[#]; Image[j]) &, imghs[[1 ;; -1 ;; 6, 1 ;; 100]]];]
```

> ```
> {303.752849, Null}
> ```

I had expected the `Fold` method to be the fastest, but it turns out this was not the case. I experimented with different combinations of parallelization and import formats and the second method is the fastest that I can achieve. Are there other options to speed up the stacking? I am aware of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29269/is-there-a-fast-method-of-generating-a-standard-deviation-image-from-a-frame-sta) but that involves a single multi-frame `.tiff` image so I can't use those methods.

Comment: In the `Fold` method you have an extra image constructor call in every step. Try moving it around the `Import` in the second argument.
A much greater speed-up should come by using ``Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadJPEG`` in place of `Import`.