# How to make a filled Ellipsoid?

Tags: plotting, packages, options, geometry

I want to make a filled `Ellipsoid`, but it seems `Filling` options doesn't work in `Graphics` options. I have a matrix

```
matrix1={{1,4},{6,8}}
```

thus I plot en ellipse from his `Eigenvalues` and `Eigenvectors`

```
valmat = Eigenvalues@matrix1;
vecmat = Eigenvectors@matrix1;
pair = {0.5, 0.5}
ellips1 = 
Ellipsoid[pair, {Abs[valmat[[1]]], Abs[valmat[[2]]]}, {vecmat[[1]], vecmat[[2]]}];
plot1 = Graphics[{Red, ellips1}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted]];
partot1 = 
Show[plot1, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["x", 18], Style["y", 18]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, None}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[13], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

The question is how to filled this ellipse with an specific color??..and also (if it's possible) the transparency on that. Thanks

Comment: What's `Ellipsoid`, what pacage is required?

Comment: @Kuba ``Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]``

Comment: Perhaps use `Disk`?

Comment: Use a disk, scale the axis and rotate.

Comment: Also, ellipsoid is a graphics, so you need to use faceform/edgeform. See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21402/5) where I use an ellipsoid.

Comment: @rm-rf I tried `FaceForm` and `EdgeForm` but they suddenly wasn't working with 2D `Ellipsoid`.

Comment: @ybeltukov Ah, I had used a 3D ellipsoid in my answer. In any case, Line -> Polygon and then faceform/edgeform is the answer, as Kuba showed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is nothing else:

```
partot1 /. Line -> Polygon
```

[image]

```
partot1 /. Line[x_] -> {Green, EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm[Opacity@.5], Polygon[x]}
```

[image]

---

Fortunatelly `Elipsoid` is not `ReadProtected` so you can use `??` to se the `UpValues` related to it. (*I suggest to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and replace/delete all contexts: `` MultivariateStatistics`Private `` so the code will be transparent*)

Really quick and not elegant fix for 2d case:

```
style[opts__, x_Ellipsoid] := Graphics[x] /. Line[y_] :> {opts, Polygon[y]} // First

ellips1 = Ellipsoid[{0.5`, 0.5`}, {10., 1.52}, {{0.4, 1.}, {-1.58, 1.}}];

Graphics[{
          style[Red, ellips1],
          Rotate[style[Green, EdgeForm@Thick, Opacity@.5, ellips1]
                 , Pi/2]
         }, Frame -> True ]
```

You can use `??` like I said before to create more general solution, unfortunatelly I'm run out of time now :/. Good luck.

[image]

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo I'm glad you like it. It is good habit to hold on with an accept a little bit. It can discourage otheres. Here for example might be some easy fix I don't know because I'm not familiar with this package :)

Comment: Thanks @Kuba for your answer, it works. But now I have other one. What if instead one ellipse, I have two. It seems there is no way to show somehow one behind the other?

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo The overlap problem is much harder and has been discussed a number of time in this site. A quick search shows this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28997/opacity-and-overlapping-multiple-polygons. Id suggest if you cant find a satisfactory existing answer you should post that as a new question.

Comment: another link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11146/how-to-quickly-calculate-intersections-of-filled-curves

Comment: @AlejandroGuarnizo Take a look at my edit, does it work for you?

Comment: @Kuba Yes...fantastic it works. I really appreciate your kind help!! :)