# How to highlight overlapping regions in RegionPlot according to the overlapping times?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the overlapping regions of several inequalities. For example,

`RegionPlot[{x + y > 0, x - y > 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1, x y < 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

The regions for the inequalities can overlap twice, three times, and so on. I want to make a plot in grayscale, such that the more times they overlap, the darker the region is. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to find regions that satisfy this inequality?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/how-to-find-regions-that-satisfy-this-inequality).

Comment: related: [overlapping polygons](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28997/5478)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way:

```
Show[RegionPlot[#, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3]] & /@ {x + y > 0, x - y > 0,  x^2 + y^2 < 1, x y < 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

Or with one plot:

```
RegionPlot[{x + y > 0, x - y > 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1, x y < 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> ConstantArray[Directive[Opacity@.3, Black], 4], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]